# Как подключится к другой схеме в PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, asp.net, postgresql

Есть web-проект на asp.net. 
Задача стоит подключиться не к схеме PUBLIC, а любой ДРУГОЙ схеме.
Как это сделать? Где прописать имя нужной схемы? Есть webconfig в проекте ASP.NET , там идёт строка подключения с именем сервера, паролем и id. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть ли доступ у пользователя указанного в строке подключния на чтение из этой схемы?
Попробуйте подключится к серверу от имени этого пользователя в PG Admin и осуществите запрос к нужной схеме. Если доступа нет добавте его.

GRANT SELECT --при необходимсти добавьте (, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE)
ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public 
TO user_name;

Comment: GRANT SELECT , INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA audit
TO user_name;

Comment: Гранты прописали. Само подключение не ясно как делать.

Answer (score 1):

Давайте так, подключиться вы можете только к базе. Схемы это сущности внутри БД и к ним у вас либо есть доступ, либо нет. Какая схема текущая определяется параметром search_path, задается на время сессии, а не в момент соединения.
Ищите в документации на ваш webconfig, где можно задать defaultSchema, если эту возможность заложил разработчик.

Или делайте первым запросом `set search_path=your_schema`

Да, и проверьте запросами, типа `select * from your_schema.your_table;` - что у вас есть доступ к таблица этой схемы, хотя бы для select-а

Comment: set search_path=your_schema - можно здесь ссылку на пример/ресурс, пожалуйста?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config-client.html или https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/runtime-config-client.html#runtime-config-client-statement